# Copy template spreadsheet to folder, then write to the new copy (google script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, copy

I need to copy a template spreadsheet to a folder, then write to C3 in the new copy.

```
//get template 
var SStemplate = "URL here";
var SStocopy = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SStemplate); 

//set destination folder
var SSdestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-hjh1DycmoweEl5ZmgxdFBRYzg");

//copy template to destination 
DriveApp.getFileById(SStocopy.getId()).makeCopy(name, SSdestFolder);
```

Once I have created the copy, how do I activate it in order to set the value of cell C3?

Here's the final working version:

```
function newprojectdocuments(){     
//activate current sheet to get new project ID
var trackerss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = trackerss.getSheetByName('AutoTracker');
var range = sheet.getRange('F1:F1');
var foldername = range.getValues();

if( foldername.toString().length === 7 ){       
//get template spreadsheet to make copy
var SStemplate = "url";
var SStocopy = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SStemplate);  
//set destination folder for new project spreadsheet
var SSdestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");    
//copy template to the spreadsheet folder
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(SStocopy.getId()).makeCopy(foldername, 
SSdestFolder);  
//open the new file
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFile.getId());
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Overview');
//Write the value you want in C3 cell
sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(foldername);
//create new folder in deal documents folder
var dealfolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
var newfolder=dealfolder.createFolder(foldername)  
if( foldername.toString().length === 7 ){
Browser.msgBox( "Project " + foldername + " folder & spreadsheet created! 
Refresh the tracker to display."  )
 }
 } else {
Browser.msgBox('Project ID must be 7 digits: YYMMDDN format') 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [makeCopy() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)) return the new File. Use it to go in it like:

```
//get template 
var SStemplate = "URL here";
var SStocopy = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SStemplate); 

//set destination folder
var SSdestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-hjh1DycmoweEl5ZmgxdFBRYzg");

//copy template to destination 
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(SStocopy.getId()).makeCopy(name, SSdestFolder);

//open the new file
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFile.getId());
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//Write the value you want in C3 cell
sheet.getRange("C3").setValue("test");
```

Comment: That worked, but I needed to change var sheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet(); to var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname'); for some reason.

Comment: My bad, I use the getActiveSpreadsheet() method instead of getActiveSheet() method. Code has been corrected.